# Magento 1.9 database query help

Tags: database, query, script

I found a query so I can mass change something in my products description. With this script:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    //->addFieldToFilter('') //Use filters to select a specific group of products
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description');

foreach($collection as $product) {
    $desc = $product->getDescription();
    // Remove parts of your description here
}
```

But this is for remove a part of description.

I want something to change a part of the description with something new.
The scenario is that inside the description has some directs links like:

```
<a href="http://address.html">
```

and must be changed like this:

```
<a href="{{store url='address.html'}}">
```

But I don't have the knowledge to fix this query to select these descriptions in 2 different languages and replace the url with the new one.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

With in following code block

```
foreach($collection as $product) {
    $desc = $product->getDescription();
    // use preg_replace to store the new description in new variable e.g.
    // in pattern you can use regex to match desired URL
    // in replacement provide the new URL 
    $newDescription = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $desc);
    $product->setDescription($newDescription);
    $product->save();
}
```